# Add 2 hours to postgresql timestamp

Tags: qgis, postgresql, timestamp

Using Qgis, I have one postgresql column named "time" with this default expression :

to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'HH24:MI:SS'::text)

I would like to add 2 hours as I'm working in a different timezone than my postgresql server.

07:46:00 would become 09:46:00

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160207/how-to-add-a-variable-number-of-hours-to-a-date-in-postgresql